# "Older" Vs "Elder"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

**Edited:**

The comparative adjectives "older" and "elder" mean the same as the superlatives "oldest" and "eldest". These comparative adjectives are often used before nouns in order to show superiority over someone or something else!
But, as you are aware, there are some practical nuances between these two and their usages! In the following sentence, I've tried to omit the nouns after them.

I would be appreciative if you could let me know how shall I change the structure of the sentences so that they could sound natural to a native speaker:

> **1)** He's my brother. He is **older**. 
>   **2)** He's my brother. He is **elder**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this is actually a worthwhile question. It's not something that you would immediately get from a dictionary search.

Comment: That's interesting @JavaLatte! You call it a worthwhile question, but I don't know why people keep downvoting it. :))

Comment: @JavaLatte My guess is that the downvotes are due to a lack of detail about what A-friend already knows about older and elder. It could be a good question with more detail. I didn’t downvote it, but I don’t think in it’s current state I would upvote it.

Comment: Let's try providing some more detail @ColleenV and see what happens later. :)

Comment: @ColleenV, I agree about the lack of detail in the question, but I was actually referring to the close votes. As I stated, this is not something that is **immediately** obvious from a dictionary entry.

Comment: @JavaLatte And if the necessary detail had been included, it would have been obvious that this question couldn’t be answered by a dictionary. The best answer to close votes and down votes is almost always to improve and clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right, but in the first sentence, **older** is a comparative derived from the adjective **old**. For a comparative, you need to specify who the brother is older than... for example by saying

> He's my brother. He is older **than me**.
>   He's my brother. He's the older **of my siblings**

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elder) describes **elder** as a noun or an adjective, but in my opinion all of the examples that they provide are actually a noun form.

If you use **elder** predicatively, as a singular noun, it must be preceded by a determiner **a** or **the**:

> He's my brother. He is **the** elder.
>   He is **an** elder.
>   They are elders.

You can also use it attributively to form a a compound noun:

> He's my elder brother.
>   He's an elder brother.

You can read more about it [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/elder-eldest-or-older-oldest).

Comment: Thank you @JavaLatte, therefore I can say: **"he is older"** or **"he is <the> elder"** with the same meaning. Right?

Comment: @A-friend I have updated my answer to correct an error in the first sentence. With the corrected versions, the meanings would be the same.

Comment: Thank you @JavaLatte. Therefore I can say: ("**He's older/elder than me"**) as well as ("**He's the elder/older**"). But ("**He's elder/older**") would be incorrect, becauae it should be preceded by "the". Right?

Comment: @A-friend. You are right about the correct versions, but the reasons for the two incorrect versions are different. "the" is only required for "elder", and "older" requires "than me".

Comment: Therefore @JavaLatte just saying: "**she is the older**" like "**she is the elder**" wouldn't be correct. Grammatically, I would be allowd to say: "**She's elder than me**" or "**she is the elder**" OR "**she is older than me**". I cannot say: "**she's the older**". Right?

Comment: @A-friend, you use "than me" with a comparative. **older** is a comparative, **elder** is an noun, so you cannot say **she's elder than me". You are right that you cannot say "she's the older" but you could say "she's the older of the two".

Comment: Ah @JavaLatte. Although you explained it before, but I don't know why I did not notice that "elder" is a "noun" and not a "comparative adjective"! However, thank you very much for your helpful efforts clarifying the issue.